# Automatic Transmition shifting gear not changing to anything other than D

Tags: automatic-transmission, mitsubishi

When I attempted to park my Mitsubishi Montero 2002, switching the gear stick from D to P did not disengage the transmission.  After running from P to D slowly a couple of times, the car did eventually disengage and I was able to Park. Any idea what went wrong there?

Comment: It sounds like the linkage is not performing its task correctly.

Comment: This is also a symptom of low ATF.

Comment: @byob  Have you checked the transmission fluid levels?  How many miles on this thing?  Have you ever changed the transmission fluid?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Transmission fluids looked OK.  The car has 90k miles, but it's 14 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the plastic end of the cable that connects the gear stick to the transmission broke, so the cable was loose.  I had to unmount the plastic covers around the gear shift to find the problem.  Our mechanic friend suggested a home built solution instead of having to replace the full cable, which would have required a lot more involvement.  The car now shifts correctly.